# Is 'up to' correct here to say?

Tags: grammaticality, expressions, prepositions

> Her hair has grown up to her shoulders

According to Merriam-Webster 'up to' used to indicate extension as far as a specified place.

Is the above example grammatically correct?

Comment: Perhaps *down* to her shoulders? Or even simply *to* her shoulders.

Comment: It's grammatical, but an odd choice of words, conjuring up visions of the hair ascending from below the shoulders!

Answer (score -1):

The phrase is grammatically correct, but it doesn't say what you want it to say.

While *up to* does indicate an extent, it's more likely to be interpreted as part of a phrasal verb *grown up*. In this case, *up* represents a direction.

In that sentence, you need *down* unless she is really rather unusual with a hairy back!

*Up to* indicating a length would be used in a sentence like "the children had hair of varying lengths, from a Number One up to shoulder-length" where you are positively indicating the end of a range. Even there, as hair generally grows down, you could still use *down to*. An unambiguous usage is with **distance,** not length: "The missile has a range of up to 60 miles".